# Mathematica spitting code back when using Resolve over a large range of interest

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, number-theory

I've just started using *Mathematica* and have encountered my first issue. Below are two commands which only differ in the range of values I am asking Mathematica to check. The first works fine, but the second just immediately gives me the code back; no error message. What is causing this? Am I asking it to do too much? If so, why does it not signal a problem?

[image]

Comment: Please post code whenever possible instead of images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Mathematica* is using an exhaustive search for your first example, testing each value of n from 2 to 2^10. By default it won't use this method if the number of test cases exceeds 10000. So in your second example it cannot resolve the `Exists` expression and returns it unchanged.

You can increase the maximum number of points for the exhaustive search using

```
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, 2^21}}]
```

then you get

```
Resolve[Exists[n, n ∈ Integers && 2^20 > n > 1, HarmonicNumber[n] > 10]]
```

> True